# Count number of matches

Tags: c++, regex

How do I count the number of matches using C++11's `std::regex`?

```
std::regex re("[^\\s]+");
std::cout << re.matches("Harry Botter - The robot who lived.").count() << std::endl;
```

Expected output:

> 7

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `regex_iterator` to generate all of the matches, then use `distance` to count them:

```
std::regex  const expression("[^\\s]+");
std::string const text("Harry Botter - The robot who lived.");

std::ptrdiff_t const match_count(std::distance(
    std::sregex_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), expression),
    std::sregex_iterator()));

std::cout << match_count << std::endl;
```

Comment: Could you explain what `std::sregex_iterator` returns and what the 'distance' between the two means?

Comment: @muntoo:  `sregex_iterator` is a typedef over `regex_iterator`, which iterates over all of the matches in the text.  `distance` is the Standard Library function that computes the number of elements in an iterator range (so, in this case, it reads all of the matches and returns how many there are).

Comment: Hi. Even if this is an old thread: I think you can drop the match_count operation (which in C++11 does not exist anyway), as (w)sregex::iterator already iterates, as you mention yourself, over the matches. Thus std::distance should return the match count. I tried it using gcc 4.6.1 and VS 2013 without match_count and it works just fine.

Comment: @gilgamash:  There is no "`match_count` operation."  `match_count` is a variable, in which I store the number of matches computed by `std::distance`.

Comment: @James: Ah, that clarifies things. Thanks for correcting me on this! Upvoted your solution :-)

Comment: How does the distance function work on an initialized sregex_iterator and a blank sregex_iterator? The confusing part is why is a blank iterator needed for the end, doesn't an iterator itself know how many times to iterate?

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

```
int countMatchInRegex(std::string s, std::string re)
{
    std::regex words_regex(re);
    auto words_begin = std::sregex_iterator(
        s.begin(), s.end(), words_regex);
    auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();

    return std::distance(words_begin, words_end);
}
```

Example usage:

```
std::cout << countMatchInRegex("Harry Botter - The robot who lived.", "[^\\s]+");
```

Output:

```
7
```