# regular expression within string c++

Tags: c++, regex, expression, match

new to regex,

what is the correct regex form I should use in order to get all occurrences of
    *Cat* (case sensitive) within the following string at any position and surrounding characters (or whitespaces)

```
std::string s(" Cat CatCat CCatt CatcatCat Cat");
std::regex e("(.*)(Cat)(.*)");
std::smatch sm;    
std::regex_match (s,sm,e);
std::cout << "there's " << sm.size() << " Cats\n";
```

I get "there's 4 Cats", when it should be 7 Cats. I'm missing 3 Cats. :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, it kinda helped me reading the following from a comment : `regex_match` "secretly" surrounds your pattern with     `^yourpatternhere$`

Comment: And then you get `sm.size()` equal `4`, because 1st match is the whole matched substring and there are 3 submatches - `.*`, `Cat` and `.*`. You should use `std::regex_search` in a condition of a `while` loop and change regex pattern to `"Cat"`.

Comment: too bad I have to use a while loop when the above looks tight and elegant

Comment: You can also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283735/count-number-of-matches). Without a loop.

Comment: sweet. Thanks @LogicStuff :)