# Word count - ignoring/subtracting double spaces

Tags: c++, string, codeblocks, fstream

I'm trying to learn some coding to broaden my scope of knowledge, and I've seemed to run into a bit of a conundrum.

I'm trying to create a program to output the number of characters, digits, punctuation, spaces, words and lines that are being read in from a file.

**Here is the text file I am reading in.**

```
  See Jack run. Jack can run fast. Jack runs after the cat. The cat's fur is black. See Jack catch the cat.
  Jack says, "I caught the cat."
  The cat says, "Meow!"
  Jack has caught 1 meowing cat. Jack wants 5 cats, but can't find any more.
```

**Here is my code**

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>

  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
  ifstream lab3;
  string word;
  lab3.open("lab3.txt");
  int countletters=0,countnum=0,countpunc=0,countspace=0,words=0,line=0;
  char character;
  if(!lab3)
  {
  cout << "Could not open file" << endl;
  return 1;
  }
  while(lab3.get(character) && !lab3.eof())
  {
  if(isalpha(character))
  {
  countletters++;
  }
  if (isdigit(character))
  {
  countnum++;
  }
  if (ispunct(character))
  {
  countpunc++;
  }
  if (isspace(character))
  {
  countspace++;
  }
  if (isalpha(character) && (isspace(character++) || ispunct(character++)))
  {
  words++;
  }
  if(character=='\n')
  {
  line++;
  }
  }
  cout << "There are " << countletters << " letters." << endl;
  cout << "There are " << countnum << " numbers." << endl;
  cout << "There are " << countpunc << " punctuations." << endl;
  cout << "There are " << countspace << " spaces." << endl;
  cout << "There are " << words << " words." << endl;
  cout << "There are " << line << " sentences." << endl;
  lab3.close();
  return 0;
  }
```

Output:

```
There are 167 letters.
There are 2 numbers.
There are 18 punctuations.
There are 52 spaces.
There are 0 words.
There are 4 sentences.
```

Some things I am hoping to learn:

1. An explanation for why the word count does not work, and replacement with working code taking into account the double spaces.
2. Advice for improvements on my code for learning purposes/efficiency.
3. Explanation for reading information in from a text file. whether its letters, numbers, punctuation whatever you may run across doing this type of coding.

Some things i am aware of:

1. `using namespace std;` is not good practice - what is the best practice for real world applications.
2. I am a beginner and this may not definitely is not the cream of the crop coding

`Thanks in advance for you aid and suggestions :)

Comment: Not sure on the other things but adding the namespace before the words like : std::string is better because different namespace can use the same words. /Advice for improvements on my code for learning purposes/efficiency./ should be asked at codereview (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Why is `character` being incremented, let alone hidden in the middle of an `if`?

Comment: What is your output, and what di you expect to get?

Comment: @chris

I was trying to say something to the effect of ...
If (character = letter AND next character = space OR next character = punctuation )
{
              Words++;
{

Comment: I just glanced at your code, so this is just a conjecture, but I think what's happening is that you are advancing the pointer to look at the next character (to see whether you are at a word boundary), but then not rewinding position in the stream after you do so.

Comment: @Mikel F

Code has been updated with output, i believe everything is in order aside from the word count.

Comment: @ThomasHedden

tried decrementing character after the word count has been updated, no effect. :(

Comment: I think that you should increment the pointer BEFORE you check it. That is, "++character" rather than "character++". I think that your statement "if (isalpha(character) && (isspace(character++) || ispunct(character++)))" says "if character is an alpha and if it is a space (then increment character) or if it is a punctuation mark (then increment character)". This can't work. In an or statement, you have to be careful not increment the character twice. I'm not sure which part of the || statement is checked first. First, increment the pointer once, then check it, then decrement it.

Comment: You could break the text into string arrays, count the characters from all strings. Count all strings. Count all characters that make the end of a sentence, though this could add to much like "Mr. Edward" is not 2 sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your method of getting the next character is by `lab3.get(character)`, incrementing the character in your word count check is not going to get the next character, only alter the value of the character you have.

Rather than trying to 'look ahead', consider preserving the last character read and checking against it to detect the end of the word on the following iteration.

`if (ispunct(character))
 {
    countpunc++;
    if (isaalpha(prevchar))
    {
       words++;
    }

  }
  if (isspace(character))
  {
    countspace++;
    if (isaalpha(prevchar))
    {
       words++;
    }

  }`

with `prevchar` initialized to zero before the loop starts, and then set equal to `character` inside the loop after all of your checks.

Also note that your numbers check is really capturing digits, so a value of 10 in your data will count as 2 numbers in your output rather than one.

Comment: Thank you so much, that code fixed the results.

I will amend the number check to account for more than single digit number as well.

Very much appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to solve all of these problems by creating variables "in_word", "in_numb", "in_punct", "in_space". Start with all their values FALSE. If the first character you encounter is an alpha, change in_word to TRUE. Keep checking until the next character no longer is an alpha and then change in_word to FALSE, increment the word count, and turn on the appropriate other variable depending on what character you have found. Only increment the word count, number count, etc., when these variables change state.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so I'm posting an answer, but I know it's not a real answer because I'm referring you to another thread.

Counting the matches for white space like they are doing here would give you a word count...

[Count number of matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283735/count-number-of-matches)

You might be able to modify this solution to count other items as well.

Without regex...
Since you are looping through the characters you could setup a flag that keeps track of the spaces, and increment the word count when it reaches another non space.

I believe putting this in your code to replace your wordcount and your spacecount portions should work.  You'll need to add an int to the top called spaceflag.  You may need to add one to the word count in order to get an accurate total.

```js
  if (isspace(character))
  {
  countspace++;
  spaceflag = 1;
  }
  else  //else says it's not a space.
  {
  if(spaceflag == 1) //if the spaceflag has been set and we run into a different type of character then we've made it to a new word.
    words++;
    spaceflag = 0; //reset the spaceflag until next one is found.
  }
  if(character=='\n')
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with 'regex' at the moment, I'd prefer to stick to basic coding before I start incorporating built in functions.